# destroy a node-cron job or cancel a node-scheduler job

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, node-cron

I am developing a nodejs application that schedules multiple cron jobs. 
By the way I got an error when I try to cancel jobs.

The situation is like below.

- I created multiple cron jobs using `node-cron` or `node-schedule`.
- A few jobs's start time already passed then I tried to cancel all the cron jobs using a script.
- I got an error like below. 
  `TypeError: testJob.destory is not a function`

Could you help me to solve this issue?

### cron module / cronManager.js

```
const cron = require("node-cron") 

// cron jobs
let testJob1
let testJob2
let testJob3

async function startCronjobs(cronTimes) {
  testJob1 = cron.schedule(cronTimes.testTime1, () => {
    console.log("test 1 job")
  }, {
    scheduled: true, 
    timezone: "America/New_York"
  })
  testJob1.start() 

testJob2 = cron.schedule(cronTimes.testTime2, () => {
    console.log("test 2 job")
  }, {
    scheduled: true, 
    timezone: "America/New_York"
  })
  testJob2.start() 

testJob3 = cron.schedule(cronTimes.testTime3, () => {
    console.log("test 3 job")
  }, {
    scheduled: true, 
    timezone: "America/New_York"
  })
  testJob3.start() 
}

async function destroyCronjobs() {
  console.log("============= Destroy node-cron Jobs ================")
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if(testJob1 !== undefined && testJob1 !== null) testJob1.destory()
    if(testJob2 !== undefined && testJob2 !== null) testJob2.destory()
    if(testJob3 !== undefined && testJob3 !== null) testJob3.destory() 
  })
}

module.exports.destroyJobs = destroyCronjobs
module.exports.startCronJobs = startCronjobs
```

### script / main.js

```
const cronManager = require("./cronManager")
const express = require("express") 
const router = express.Router() 

router.post("/start", wrapper(async (req, res) => {
    await cronManager.startCronjobs()
}))

router.post("/destroy", wrapper(async (req, res) => {
    await cronManager.destoryCronjobs()
}))
```

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 1):

You have an typo error in your code you have `testJob1.destory()` but it should be `testJob.destroy()`

[destroy()](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron#destroy) will be stopped and completely destroy the scheduled task.

Assume that this the sample code, so that its missing some argument for `cronManager.startCronjobs()` and also this function not returning any `promise` to use `await`.

Comment: If there is a job that already started and then what if I try to destroy the job?

Comment: It will destroy, Change `testJob1.destory()` to `testJob.destroy()`

Comment: I tried it and it was same. I just rewrite my code to show it here. So the type error wasn't the issue.

Comment: Then Update your question

Comment: I solved the issue. The problem was a type issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @vcvcvcvc Can you please tell a bit more about what was the issue and how you solved it. I am also getting the same error. Thanks!

Comment: Does the cron object will destroy itself after cron execution is done ?
Does it accessible after cron execution is done ? @ŞivāSankĂr
just for knowledge.